# How to solve this error: 'Firebase' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use firebase on react, but I'm getting the " 'firebase' is not defined " error.
I installed firebase, and I have the firebase configuration on another file that I import on the code. The firebaseConfig.

My code

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { firebaseConfig } from "./config";
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = auth(firebase.auth);
const firestore = firestore(firebase.firestore);

const GoogleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
GoogleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup();
```

Comment: you should probably define firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a mix of the older namespaces syntax, and the newer modular syntax. I recommend starting from the relevant Firebase documentation and picking one of the other, not a combination of both.

The imports and getting services in v9 are:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { firebaseConfig } from "./config";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting started with Auth in the v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#web-version-9), [getting starting with Firestore in the v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9) and the [upgrade guide to the v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

You can  try write npm install -g firebase-tools in your terminal project